# How can I create a CSS selector for both class and attribute value?

Tags: html, css

How do I define a CSS style applying to this link with `class="disney"` and `target="_blank"`?

```
  <a class="disney" href="http://www.disney.com" target="_blank">disney.com</a>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try that:

```
.disney[target="_blank"] {
    color: red;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4dW2p/

Comment: No need to judge each other language skills I think.It does not say that it needs to be targeted in css. However this does not work if you have style selector a[target="_blank" aswell. How to overwrite that?

Comment: It works - example: http://jsfiddle.net/4dW2p/1/
You can try adding `!important` to example `color: red !important` if you have problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following selector should do it:

```
a.disney[target="_blank"] {
  /* your styles here */
}
```

Support is basically universal by now - all the major browsers have supported it for a long time. See [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).